# switch indices in 4th order tensor with python

Tags: python, numpy, tensor

I would like to replicate the following operation:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.eye(3)
A = np.einsum("ij,kl->ikjl", a,a)
```

I have the following:

```
def IndexPermutation(stringWithTensorIndices, Tensor):

    # Function to split the string with the indices
    def split(word): 
       return [char for char in word]
    
    # Gets indices from string               
    a, b, c, d = split(stringWithTensorIndices) 
    
    store=np.zeros((3,3,3,3))

    # Performs the tensor index permutations
    for i in [0,1,2]:
        for j in [0,1,2]:
            for k in [0,1,2]:
                for l in [0,1,2]:
                    store[i,j,k,l]=Tensor[vars()[a],vars()[b],vars()[c],vars()[d]]
                    
    return store
```

I would like to remove the `vars()` function. And currently, it is only accepting "ij" "kl" and afterward permuting the indices (equivalent to einsum ("some combination of ijkl -> ijkl").

Can anyone give me a hand with this?

Comment: I think there needs to be a bit more information. It's not very clear to me what value `stringWithTensorIndices` should have? Your `a,b,c,d=split(...)` seems to assume it would be an exactly four character string. The `vars()` stuff is just confusing - it will return a dictionary of all the defined variables (so `vars()["a"]` is equal to `a`. What is it intended to accomplish?

Comment: hi, since this is for 4th order tensor it is expecting 4 indices (I,j,k,l). The vars part I do not like... it will take the indices from the under, e.g., a=i, b=k, c=j, d= l

Comment: Oh, I see! So `vars()[a]` resolves to `i`, your loop variable. But in that case you might as well just have `Tensor[i,j,k,l]`, since the names of your loop variables are hard-coded? I suppose the idea is to allow arbitrary ordering (e.g. "jkli")?

Comment: The idea is to have arbitrary ijkl indices. vars()[a] will take the loop value of the corresponding index supplied by the user. It feels quirky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that what you want to do is provide some input `stringWithTensorIndices` with values like `"ijkl"` or `"jlki"` to determine how the summation will be achieved. Then the logic of the loop is

- for the case where the input is "jlki", a="j"
- and so `vars()[a]` = `vars()["j"]`
- this is the value of the loop variable `j`
- so you get `store[i,j,k,l] = Tensor[j,l,k,i]`

There are a few things to say here.

First, your `split` function isn't doing anything for you. `a,b,c,d = "jkli"` will correctly resolve to `a="j"` etc. because a string can itself be treated as a Python collection. There's no safety for incorrect user input either way. Best practice might be to catch the `ValueError` and provide an informative exception. In practice I think we'll take a different approach anyway.

Now, the important part. At any point in your heavily-nested loop, you are going to have some indices `[i, j, k, l]` (these being your loop variables). The input is kind of like a key for choosing from this collection of indices.

For example, "jlki" should pick out `indices[1], indices[3], indices[2], indices[0]`.

What we need is a helper function:

```py
tensor_indices = "iljk"
lookup = {"i": 0, "j": 1, "k": 2, "l": 3}
mapped_indices = [lookup[x] for x in tensor_indices]


def get_indices(loop_indices, mapped_indices):
    # loop_indices is [i, j, k, l], changes every iteration
    # mapped indices is [0, 3, 1, 2], never changes

    for_tensor = tuple(loop_indices[x] for x in mapped_indices)

    return for_tensor  # (i, l, j, k), as was required
```

Returning as a tuple, not a list, is important because if you index the multi-dimensional numpy array `a` with a list, `a[[0,2,1,0]]`, that is quite different to indexing it as `a[0,2,1,0]`. The former extracts slices from the array along its first dimension, the latter picks out a specific value.

Fortunately, Python will generally try to treat a tuple like a comma-separated list of variables, so `a[t]` where `t = (0,2,1,0)` is equivalent to `a[0,2,1,0]`.

With this in hand I think we can move to a full solution:

```py
import numpy as np
from typing import List, Tuple
# type annotations are useful, and mean you don't have to use
# names like stringWithTensorIndices to keep track


def get_indices(
    loop_indices: List[int], mapped_indices: List[int]
) -> Tuple[int, int, int, int]:
    """
    get_indices
    
    This function takes a set of loop variables, e.g. i, j, k, l
    and uses a set of mapped indices (e.g. [0, 1, 1, 2] for 'ijjk')
    and returns loop variables chosen according to the mapping
    (i.e. (i, j, j, k) in this example).

    """
    for_tensor = tuple(loop_indices[x] for x in mapped_indices)

    return for_tensor  # (i, l, j, k), as was required


def index_permutation(tensor_indices: str, tensor: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    index_permutation

    Permutes indices of a tensor

    Inputs:
        tensor_indices - e.g. "ijkl"
        tensor - the tensor to operate on

    Output:
        new_tensor - the resulting tensor

    """
    lookup = {"i": 0, "j": 1, "k": 2, "l": 3}
    # for e.g. 'iljk' we want 0, 3, 1, 2:
    mapped_indices = [lookup[x] for x in tensor_indices]

    dim = 3
    shape = (dim, dim, dim, dim)
    new_tensor = np.zeros(shape)

    for i in range(dim):
        for j in range(dim):
            for k in range(dim):
                for l in range(dim):
                    indices = [i, j, k, l]
                    reordered = get_indices(indices, mapped_indices)
                    new_tensor[i,j,k,l]=Tensor[reordered]

    return store
```

#### Miscellania

I've gone ahead and implemented some best-practices here:

- D.R.Y. (don't repeat yourself) - a lot of stuff to change simultaneously if you want to change the behaviour in future, so [0,1,2] for example just gets stored as one list that you reference four times
- builtin iterators like `range(N)`, `enumerate`, `zip` are handy
- docstrings, comments - future you will thank you even if no-one else does
- type annotations - even if you aren't using `mypy` to check types, they aid readability *especially* where you have a bunch of variables with similar names. In the newest python you don't even need `List`, regular `list[int]` will do.
- standard python conventions - `snake_case` for variable and function names, `CamelCase` for class names

One thing I haven't done is attempted to eliminate that heavily nested loop. There are ways to do that with `numpy` (it's what it's good at), but it seemed to me that this would be beside the point of the exercise.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! Leaving the vars() function is a relief. 
In `def get_indices(loop_indices: List[int], mapped_indices: List[int]) -> List[int]:`. Does python have type check now? Or is this for the user to know what to input? I did not refer in the question but I am using asserts to check the type of the input. In the `index_permutation`the tensor should be a `ndarray` and in the `new_tensor[i,j,k,l]=tensor[reordered]` I cannot get the value out of the `ndarray` so I had to unfold the list `tensor[reordered[0], reordered[1], reordered[2], reordered[3] ]`. Is this reproducible on your side?

Comment: Yes - Python 3.5+ has support for type checking ([see PEP484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/)). Practically speaking, you should check out [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), which is the type-checker of choice.

Ah, that's right - `np.array` is a function that _returns_ an `np.ndarray`. I've edited the answer.

Finally, my bad, I forgot you'd get `Tensor[[i,l,j,k]]` as your result. Confusingly, this is handled differently to `Tensor[(i,l,j,k)]`! Will edit accordingly.